# How to find text files with a certain phrase (including quotation marks) on mac?

Tags: macos

I want to find all text files containing source-code like `class="some class"`. When using the Finder search, it is not working, seems like Finder is looking for `"some class"`. Recommendations to other programs are welcome, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the Terminal:

```
grep -r 'class="some class"' .
```

You can replace that "." with any dirname you want, or a filename pattern like `*.css`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try EasyFind, freeware on the App Store. Can check inside packages & also use strict or fuzzy search. It's not massively fast, but it does get there.

Comment: I found this too, did not work for finding text inside files at all for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try escaping the quotes with one or two backslashes:

```
class=\\"some class\\"
```

From the command line could be easier:
http://support.apple.com/kb/TA25275

> As in traditional BSD unix, the backslash character, "\", may be used
>   before an illegal character to cause it to be parsed as part of the
>   search string:
>
> `find / -name Mac\\ NC\\ # -print &`

Comment: Then Finder won’t find anything…